# I want to mount an external HD connected to one mac on my main mac va my network

Tags: network, backup, time-machine, imac, mac-mini

I have a Mac Mini 2012 running Catalina 10.15.7 with a 4TB external HD plugged in via USB. I want to mount this external HD on my IMac 2020 running Big Sur 11.7.4 over my network so I can use it for Time Machine backups.

I have set up sharing correctly on the mac mini, I have shared the mac mini internal HD AND the external HD and set the permissions so that the admin user on both the mac mini and the iMac an access the shares.

When I access the mac mini via the network from my imac I can see all the shared volumes.
I can mount and access the mac mini internal HD but when i try to mount the external HD I get the following message:

"The operation cant be completed because the original item for "Network-BU-01" cant be found - when i try to access using the Admin user credentials from the shared mac mini

OR

"The operation cant be completed because the original item for "Network-BU-01" cant be found - when i try to access using the user credentials for a new user with full access permissions set up on the mac mini

OR

When I launch Time Machine on my iMac, I can see the shared external HD in the mac mini as a valid back up disk, but when I try to connect via time machine I get the message:

"There as an error authenticating with the provided username or password" - this happens if i try to connect as the admin "owner" on the mac mini, or as new user with full access permissions set up on the mac mini.

I have done the same thing before, with an older mac mini and the same imac, and it worked perfectly and this is driving me insane. I want to set it up like this so I can also connect my macbook pro, my wifes macbook pro and my daughters macbook air to the mac mini to run daily backups via Time Machine.

Anyone have any bright ideas?

Comment: Why are you sharing your internal drive?  Just share the volume you are interested in.  Next, what command are you using ?

Comment: I only shared the internal drive to to check that the sharing function was working. The fact that the internal HD can be shared and mounted shows that it is set up correctly. Which is why it’s so weird that the external he can be mounted.

Comment: I’m using SMB for the sharing protocol.

Comment: Is "Ignore ownership on this volume" checked on the external drive? (In Get Info)